# How to check if a element or an element within the another element exists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to get the list of customers in a seperate file which have Product/ProductGroup/ProductGroupName value as 'xyz' for an example . 
I have tried with below snippet which works for me only if all required nodes are present for all customers .

```
//get list of required customers
var filteredcustomers = xDoc.Root.Element("CustomerCollection").
                           Elements("Customer").
                           Where(a => a.Element("Product").
                                   Element("ProductGroup").
                                   Element("ProductGroupName").
                                   Value == "xyz");
// create new file
 XDocument xmlOut = new  XDocument ();
 XElement rootNode = new XElement("Root");
 xmlOut.Add(rootNode);
 xmlOut.Root.Add(new XElement("CustomerCollection"));
 xmlOut.Descendants("CustomerCollection").FirstOrDefault().Add(filteredcustomers);
 xmlOut.save("path");
```

But there are customers in file which is not having `Product` node or `ProductGroup` node or do not have `ProductGroupName` element itself .
In that scenario , this query is not working even if a single customer is having issues with expected nodes. How can I filter the list of proper customers which have all required fields .

Below is the sample xml file :

```
<Root>
    <CustomerCollection>
        <Customer>
            <Product>
                <ProductGroup>
                    <ProductGroupId>123</ProductGroupId>
                    <ProductGroupName>xyz</ProductGroupName>
                </ProductGroup>
            </Product>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <Product>
                <ProductGroup>
                    <!-- ProductGroupName element is Missing-->
                    <ProductGroupId>123</ProductGroupId>
                </ProductGroup>
            </Product>
        </Customer>
        <Customer>
            <Product>
                <!-- ProductGroup element is missing-->
            </Product>
        </Customer>

    </CustomerCollection>
</Root
```

Thank you for your help in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) to check if an element exists.

```
var filteredcustomers = xDoc.Root.Element("CustomerCollection").
                            Elements("Customer").Where(a => 
                                a.Element("Product").Elements("ProductGroup").Elements("ProductGroupName").Any() 
                                &&
                                a.Element("Product").Element("ProductGroup").Element("ProductGroupName").Value == "xyz");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("ProductGroup")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Element("ProductGroupName") == "xyz")
                .Select(x => new { id = (string)x.Element("ProductGroupId"), name = (string)x.Element("ProductGroupName") })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```